# Php laravel route.php does not work on a specific call

Tags: php, laravel, routes, directory

My site's directory structure is;

**site** -> app -> **public** 
                         --> soundfiles (directory having sounds files)

```
route.php: Route::get("soundfiles", "controller@soundfiles");
```

when I hit mysite/soundfiles it shows me soudfiles directory instead of going to => controller@soundfiles.

I want it does not show sound files. where is the problem.

Comment: is controller correct ?

Comment: yes it is, sometimes it goes controller but most of the time it shows directory

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
Route::get("/soundfiles", "soundfilescontroller@soundfiles");
```

Route::get('/urlalias', 'controllerName@functionName');

OR

Add this to your htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm using as you said, but here I just write to give hint.

Comment: Okay please check second part of my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is serving the directory instead of routing everything through `index.php`. Work out whether you're using Nginx or Apache and ensure you've got it configured correctly. Laravel ships with a valid `.htaccess` file for Apache, read the docs for how to configure Nginx.